# Drupal event showing in view condition

Tags: views

I have three content types

1. Event
2. Generic event
3. Announcement
   I have to show all in a view.

I have to show 5 *Event* in view, if any event expires then *Generic event* will show to fulfil 5 event example(if one event expire from 5 that means it becomes 4 then generic event will show in place of expire event and total number of event becomes 5).

Announcement will show in same view but there is no limit.

How can i achieve this i am using Drupal 7 and views module.

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'eventslideshow';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->human_name = 'eventslideshow';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Current & Upcoming Events';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '10';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'slideshow';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['slideshow_type'] = 'views_slideshow_cycle';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['slideshow_skin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['skin_info'] = array(
  'class' => 'default',
  'name' => 'Default',
  'module' => 'views_slideshow',
  'path' => '',
  'stylesheets' => array(),
);
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['widgets']['top']['views_slideshow_pager']['weight'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['widgets']['top']['views_slideshow_pager']['type'] = 'views_slideshow_pager_fields';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['widgets']['top']['views_slideshow_pager']['views_slideshow_pager_fields_fields'] = array(
  'nid' => 0,
  'field_banner_image' => 0,
  'title' => 0,
  'type' => 0,
  'field_event_date_new' => 0,
  'field_event_location' => 0,
);
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['widgets']['top']['views_slideshow_controls']['weight'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['widgets']['top']['views_slideshow_controls']['type'] = 'views_slideshow_controls_text';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['widgets']['top']['views_slideshow_slide_counter']['weight'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['widgets']['bottom']['views_slideshow_pager']['weight'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['widgets']['bottom']['views_slideshow_pager']['type'] = 'views_slideshow_pager_fields';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['widgets']['bottom']['views_slideshow_pager']['views_slideshow_pager_fields_fields'] = array(
  'nid' => 0,
  'field_banner_image' => 0,
  'title' => 0,
  'type' => 0,
  'field_event_date_new' => 0,
  'field_event_location' => 0,
);
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['widgets']['bottom']['views_slideshow_controls']['weight'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['widgets']['bottom']['views_slideshow_controls']['type'] = 'views_slideshow_controls_text';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['widgets']['bottom']['views_slideshow_slide_counter']['enable'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['widgets']['bottom']['views_slideshow_slide_counter']['weight'] = '2';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['views_slideshow_cycle']['effect'] = 'scrollLeft';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['views_slideshow_cycle']['timeout'] = '5000';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['views_slideshow_cycle']['speed'] = '700';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['views_slideshow_cycle']['delay'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['views_slideshow_cycle']['pause'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['views_slideshow_cycle']['start_paused'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['views_slideshow_cycle']['remember_slide_days'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['views_slideshow_cycle']['items_per_slide'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['views_slideshow_cycle']['wait_for_image_load_timeout'] = '3000';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['views_slideshow_cycle']['cleartype'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['views_slideshow_cycle']['cleartypenobg'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'panels_fields';
$handler->display->display_options['row_options']['inline'] = array(
  'field_banner_image' => 'field_banner_image',
);
$handler->display->display_options['row_options']['layout'] = 'onecol';
$handler->display->display_options['row_options']['regions'] = array(
  'nid' => 'middle',
  'field_banner_image' => 'middle',
  'title' => 'middle',
  'type' => 'middle',
  'field_event_date_new' => 'middle',
  'field_event_location' => 'middle',
);
/* Field: Content: Nid */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['id'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['field'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Banner Image */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_banner_image']['id'] = 'field_banner_image';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_banner_image']['table'] = 'field_data_field_banner_image';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_banner_image']['field'] = 'field_banner_image';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_banner_image']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_banner_image']['alter']['alter_text'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_banner_image']['alter']['text'] = '[field_banner_image]</div><div class="slide_right">';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_banner_image']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_banner_image']['click_sort_column'] = 'fid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_banner_image']['settings'] = array(
  'image_style' => 'slideshow',
  'image_link' => '',
);
/* Field: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['text'] = '<div class="other_filed">[title] ';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type']['field'] = 'type';
/* Field: Content: Event Date */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_event_date_new']['id'] = 'field_event_date_new';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_event_date_new']['table'] = 'field_data_field_event_date_new';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_event_date_new']['field'] = 'field_event_date_new';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_event_date_new']['settings'] = array(
  'format_type' => 'long',
  'fromto' => 'value',
  'multiple_number' => '',
  'multiple_from' => '',
  'multiple_to' => '',
);
/* Field: Content: Event Location */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_event_location']['id'] = 'field_event_location';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_event_location']['table'] = 'field_data_field_event_location';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_event_location']['field'] = 'field_event_location';
/* Sort criterion: Content: Post date */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['order'] = 'DESC';
$handler->display->display_options['filter_groups']['operator'] = 'OR';
$handler->display->display_options['filter_groups']['groups'] = array(
  1 => 'AND',
  2 => 'AND',
);
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type_1']['id'] = 'type_1';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type_1']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type_1']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type_1']['group_type'] = 'count';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type_1']['value'] = array(
  'event' => 'event',
);
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type_1']['group'] = 1;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Event Date - end date (field_event_date_new:value2) */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_event_date_new_value2']['id'] = 'field_event_date_new_value2';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_event_date_new_value2']['table'] = 'field_data_field_event_date_new';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_event_date_new_value2']['field'] = 'field_event_date_new_value2';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_event_date_new_value2']['operator'] = '>';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_event_date_new_value2']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_event_date_new_value2']['granularity'] = 'minute';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_event_date_new_value2']['form_type'] = 'date_popup';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_event_date_new_value2']['default_date'] = 'now';
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status_1']['id'] = 'status_1';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status_1']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status_1']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status_1']['value'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status_1']['group'] = 2;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  'announcements' => 'announcements',
);
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['group'] = 2;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Show announcements in slideshow (field_show_announcements) */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_show_announcements_value']['id'] = 'field_show_announcements_value';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_show_announcements_value']['table'] = 'field_data_field_show_announcements';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_show_announcements_value']['field'] = 'field_show_announcements_value';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_show_announcements_value']['value'] = array(
  1 => '1',
);
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_show_announcements_value']['group'] = 2;

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['hide_admin_links'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'eventslideshow';

/* Display: Block */
$handler = $view->new_display('block', 'Block', 'block');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['hide_admin_links'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['pager'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'some';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '10';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['offset'] = '0';
```

Comment: I have done something similar but a little more complex before with 2 views and some custom code in a cusstom module that implements hook_views_pre_render to swap results into the first view from the second view when it was appropriate. Sorry I can't elaborate more right now.